# How can I include a single post inside a Wp_query?

Tags: php, wordpress

My current query looks like this.

```
$tag_id = 276;
$tag = get_tag($tag_id);
$today = date( "Y-m-d" );

$args  = array(
    'post_type'     => array(
                        'post',
                        'review',
                        'cardguide'
                    ),
    'taxonomy'      => 'post_tag',
    'tag_id'        => $tag_id,
    'posts_per_page'=> - 1,
    'orderby'       => 'id',
    'order'         => 'DESC',

    'meta_key'      => 'event_end_date',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'=> 'AND',
        array(
            'key'    => 'event_start_date',
            'value'  => $today,
            'compare'=> '<=',
            'type'   => 'DATE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'    => 'event_end_date',
            'value'  => $today,
            'compare'=> '>=',
            'type'   => 'DATE'
        )
    )

);
$my_query = new Wp_query( $args );
```

I want to include a single post *(can use post id)* into this query. The post may not obey each of the rules I defined inside `$args`. And also would like to have it always on top of the list *(featured item)*.

Comment: you can also use `post__in` with multiple `post_id` or single `post_id`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the same post by id for this query every time, then just do a separate [get_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) call like:

```
$featured_item = get_post( 123 ); // replace 123 with your id
```

This will prevent you from having to worry about "obeying each of the rules" you've defined above.  Plus, if you always want it "on top", then you can pump out the values of $featured_item before you run your query loop.